# PODAM - Why does podam assigns same values each generation?

Tags: java, jemos-podam

I wrote the following code

```
PodamFactory factory = new PodamFactoryImpl();
Honda honda1 = factory.manufacturePojo(Honda.class);
System.out.println(honda1.toString());
Honda honda2 = factory.manufacturePojoWithFullData(Honda.class);
System.out.println(honda2.toString());
```

this is Honda Class

```
public class Honda {

    String name;
    int version;

    public Honda(String name, int version) {
        this.name = name;
        this.version = version;
    }
...
}
```

And I get

```
Honda{name='c00iZ2ponC', version=883048266}
Honda{name='c00iZ2ponC', version=883048266}
```

Why does podam assigns same values each generation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens due to so called memoization, which does caching of produced objects by type. This feature was enabled by default in some of PODAM's versions.

You can disable it the following way

```
PodamFactory factory = new PodamFactoryImpl();
factory.getStrategy().setMemoizationEnabled(false);
```